# prediction_regression_tree_ caret: Error in '[.data.frame'(m, labs) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, r-caret, rpart

Im trying to train a regression tree in using the train-function from caret. It worked with a linear model. But when I tried a regression tree the following error came: `Error in '[.data.frame'(m, labs) : undefined columns selected`

the data frame contains of 450+ dummy variables made from categorical variables using the fastDummies-package. Is it a problem that the data frame consists of that many dummies, where there could be few 1's and many zeroes in each variable?

I have tried to versions:

```
 model_reg_tree <- train(
  x =  data_train[, names(data_train) != "Outcome"],
  y = data_train$Outcome,
  data = data_train, 
  method = 'rpart',
  tuneLength = 10,
  trControl = kontroller_cv)
```

and

```
 model_reg_træ <- train(
  Outcome ~ .,
  data = data_train, 
  method = 'rpart',
  tuneLength = 10,
  trControl = kontroller_cv)
```

the controls:

```
    kontroller_cv <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",                      
  number = 10 ,                       
  summaryFunction = defaultSummary,  
  verboseIter = TRUE,                 
  index = folds                       
)
```

data (only some of it, did not have space enough to all of it)

```
dput(head(data_train))
structure(list(Medlem_Køn = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Alder_ind = c(20, 
20, 54, 36, 51, 51), Elev_ind = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Elev_ud = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Ledig_ind = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Outcome = c(492L, 
1158L, 2161L, 7365L, 8522L, 5326L), PostNr_ud_87 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_47 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_98 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_74 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    PostNr_ud_55 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_64 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_94 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_86 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_90 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_52 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_95 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_62 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_54 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_85 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_58 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_93 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_63 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_26 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_67 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_42 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_77 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_00 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_99 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_20 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_71 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_89 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_41 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_92 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_75 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_76 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_44 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_65 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_57 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), PostNr_ud_49 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_45 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_78 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_60 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_84 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_59 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_88 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_61 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_29 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_82 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_34 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_56 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_68 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_83 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_96 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_69 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_24 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_28 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_72 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_97 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_32 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_40 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_35 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_37 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_Odense = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_33 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_66 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_79 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_70 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_21 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_30 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L), PostNr_ud_53 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_73 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_36 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_Frd_c = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_23 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_27 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_43 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_22 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_46 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_48 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_80 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_25 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), PostNr_ud_Kbh_v = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_31 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PostNr_ud_Kbh_K = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Sektor_ind_Pædagogisk Sektor` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Sektor_ind_Social- og Sundhedssektoren` = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `Sektor_ind_Teknik- og Servicesektoren` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Sektor_ind_Kost- og Servicesektoren` = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `Sektor_ind_Uden sektor` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Stilling_ind_Dagplejer = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Stilling_ind_Sygehjælpere = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L), `Stilling_ind_Anden stilling` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L), `Stilling_ind_Social og sundhedshjælper` = c(0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Stilling_ind_Social og sundhedsassistent` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stilling_ind_Pædagogmedhjælper = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stilling_ind_Hjemmehjælper = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Stilling_ind_Pædagog, Dag - Københavns Kommune` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Stilling_ind_Pædagogisk assistent - Dag-området` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Leder_ud_Nej = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), `Leder_ud_Praksisnær ledelse` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), `Leder_ud_Strategisk ledelse` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Horsens` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `Afd_navn_ind_Næstved, Nedlagt` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Vendsyssel` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Herning` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), `Afd_navn_ind_Ikke defineret konv.` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Sønderborg` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Nordjylland` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Silkeb-Skanderbo` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Odense` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Randers` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Tønder,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Djursland,Nedlag` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Sydfyn` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Aabenraa,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Afd_navn_ind_KLS = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Esbjerg` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Slagelse,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Thisted-Morsø` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Hillerød,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Viborg` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Frederikshavn` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA SOSU` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Mariagerfjord` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Vejle` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Århus` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Varde` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Sydøstjy,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Brønderslev,Nedl` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Holstebro` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_Kalundborg,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Kolding` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Lolland` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Sjælland omr Hol` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF mellem broerne,N` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Afd_navn_ind_LFS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Vestlolland,Nedl` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Skive` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Sønderjylland` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Vojens,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Helsingør,Nedlag` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Nordsjælland` = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA 1` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Frederikssund` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Fyn` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Bornholm` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_Odsher-Svinn,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Sjælland omr Nor` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Vendsyssel,Nedla` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Lillebælt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Roskilde` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Fredericia,Nedla` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Ringsted,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Middelfart,Nedla` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Østlolland,Nedla` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_TF,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Morsø,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Køge` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Ringkøb,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Guldborgsund` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Ribe,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_Sydsjælland, Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Sjylland,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA/PMF Kbh. Syd` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Viborg amt,Nedla` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_Møn, Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Himmerland,Nedla` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Århus,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Sydsjælland` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Kbh/frb,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF afdeling 4` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_FOA Sjælland omr Mid` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Frederiksborg,Ne` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF afdeling 1` = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Silkeborg,Nedlag` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Afd_navn_ind_Afd.99 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_PMF Bornholm,Nedlagt` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Afd_navn_ind_Tidl. PMF` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MedlemstypeOmråde_ind_Erhvervsaktiv = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MedlemstypeOmråde_ind_Pensionist = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MedlemstypeOmråde_ind_Hvilende = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MedlemstypeOmråde_ind_Efterløn = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MedlemstypeOmråde_ud_Erhvervsaktiv = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), MedlemstypeOmråde_ud_Efterløn = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MedlemstypeOmråde_ud_Pensionist = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), MedlemstypeOmråde_ud_Hvilende = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Medlemstype_ud_Fuldtid o 30 år u/efbid` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Medlemstype_ud_Fleksibel efterløn, fuldtid` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Medlemstype_ud_Anden medlemstype` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `Medlemstype_ud_Pensionist over 65 år` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), `Medlemstype_ud_Fuldtid o 60 år med efterlønsbevis` = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Medlemstype_ud_Fuldtid m/efterlønsbidrag` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Medlemstype_ud_Forbund, fuldtid` = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Medlemstype_ud_Pensionist under 65 år` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Medlemstype_ud_Fuldtid u 30 år u/efbid` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Sektor_ud_Pædagogisk Sektor` = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Sektor_ud_Social- og Sundhedssektoren` = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), `Sektor_ud_Teknik- og Servicesektoren` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Sektor_ud_Uden sektor` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Sektor_ud_Kost- og Servicesektoren` = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Fagruppe_ud_Dagplejere = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Sygehjælpere = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Plejere = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    `Fagruppe_ud_FOA RBR Rådhus, Biblioteks- og Regionsbetjente` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Uden sektortilhør` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Social-og sundhedshjælpere` = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Køkken = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Rengøring = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L
    ), `Fagruppe_ud_Social-og sundhedsassistenter` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Plejehjemstekniker` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Hjemmehjælpere = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Dagplejepædagoger mv` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Pædagogmedhjælpere og pædagogiske assistenter` = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Portører = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Personale ved højskoler og private kantiner mv` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Plejehjemsassistenter = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Formænd under Formandsoverenskomsten` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Brand og Redning` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Beskæftigelsesvejledere = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Værksstedsassistenter/-ledere` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Omsorgsmedhjælpere og pædagogiske assistenter` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Trafikservice` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Ledere og Mellemledere (Tidl. Hjemmehjælpsledere)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Serviceassistenter og -medarbejdere` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Ledende servicepersonale` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Øvrige indenfor social-og sundheds sektor` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Regionsansatte uden for FOA` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_LFS, dag` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Teknisk Ledelse` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Handicapledsagere = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Søfart` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Øvrige indenfor teknik-og service sektoren` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Sport (Bade- og Idrætsassistenter)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Parkering` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Husmedhjælpere i staten` = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Øvrige indenfor pædagogisk sektor` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Kantineledere = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_LFS, døgn` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Handicaphjælpere = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Servicechefer/-ledere og teamkoordinatorer` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Specialarbejdere = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Øvrige indenfor Kost-og service sektoren` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Bybuschauffører` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Håndværkere = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Neurofysiologi assistenter` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Vaskeripersonale = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Teknik og Service (Skoler)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Fodterapeuter = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_UDGÅET Idrætsassistenter` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Legepladsansatte = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_UDGÅET Arbejdsledere` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Rengøringsledere = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Pædagogiske konsulenter` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Piccoloer og Piccoliner` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Tilsynsførende assistenter` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Operationsteknikere = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Kedel-, maskin- og motorpassere` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_Pædagogiske pladsanvisere` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_FOA Ambulance` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Gymnastikpædagoger = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fagruppe_ud_Miljøkontrollører = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Fagruppe_ud_UDGÅET Skolebetjente/-pedeller og -medhjælpere` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stilling_ud_Dagplejere = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Stilling_ud_Sygehjælpere = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L), Stilling_ud_Anden_stilling = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L), `Stilling_ud_Social og sundhedshjælper` = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stilling_ud_Husassistent = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Stilling_ud_Social og sundhedsassistent` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stilling_ud_Hjemmehjælper = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Stilling_ud_Pædagogmedhjælper = c(1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Stilling_ud_Pædagogisk assistent - Dag-området` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Stilling_ud_Pædagog = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Det Faglige Hus - A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_BUPL-A-Børne- og ungdomspædagogernes A-k` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Ikke overflyttet` = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_HK Hovedstaden` = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_3F-Fælles faglig A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Huslige arbejderes a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Pædagogiske Medhjælperes Fælles A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Kvindelige Arbejderes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_KRIFA-Kristelig A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_bryggeriarb. a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_NNF-Fødevareforbundets A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Frisørfagets og keramikernes a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_DLF-A Lærernes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_TL-Teknikernes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Ledernes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Træ-Industri-Bygs arbejdsløshedskasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Business Danmarks A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Træindustriarb. arb.løsh.kas.` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Beklædnings- og Tekstilarbejder A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_DSA-Din Sundhedsfaglige A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_FTF-A Funktionærernes og Tjenestemænd.` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Metalarbejdernes Arbejdsløshedskasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_FFA-Frie Funktionærers A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Grafisk Arbejdsløshedskasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_kommunalarb. arbejdsløshedskasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_DANA-A-kasse for selvstændige` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_RBF's Arbejdsløshedskasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_FOA-Fag og Arbejdes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_hotel. og rest.pers. a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_ASE = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Funktionærernes og Servicefagenes A-kas.` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_SL-Socialpædagogernes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Min A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_A-kasse for Journalistik, Kommunikation` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Gastronomernes a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Forsvarets Arbejdsløshedskasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_CA A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_BFA-Byggefagenes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_MA-Magistrenes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_AAK-Akademikernes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Norge = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_EL-Fagets A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Færøerne = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Tjenerne, musik. og artis. a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Sverige = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Tyskland = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Akademikernes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Murerfagets arb.løsh.kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Frisører, Artister og Maritim A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Bogb.- og kartonagearb. a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Island = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Storbritanien = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Bogtrykfagets a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Sø-restaurationens a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Prosa og Merkonomernes A-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Spanien = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Irland = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Jurist- og økonom. a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Journalisternes Arbejdsløshedskasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Reprofagets a-kasse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Grækenland = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Holland = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_3.lande = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Overflyttet_fra_akasse_Østrig = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Ingen Hverv` = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Andre hverv` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Sektorbestyrelse = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Andre afdelingshverv` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Afd. sektorformand` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Afdelingsbestyrelse = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Bestyrelsesudvalg = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_SOSU-uddannelsesråd` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Afdelingsnæstformand = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Ungdomsansvarlig = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Ældreråd = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Fællesbest. SOSU` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_PGU uddannelsesråd` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Klubformand = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_HB-suppleant(amt)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Amtselevkoordinator = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_AMU udd-udvalg` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_2. HB-suppl. (sekt)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Faglig sekretær` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Afd. daglige ledelse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Elevansvarlig(SOSU)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Gæstelærer = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Fanebærer = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Faggrupperepræsentan = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_PGU udd-råd supplean` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Afdelingskassere = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Seniorklub = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Kritisk revisorsupp.` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Afdelingsformand = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_HB-medlem(amt)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Kritisk revisor` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_AMU udd-udvalg suppl` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Ungdomsnetværket = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Landselevbestyrelse = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_Sektorformand = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_3. HB-suppl. (sekt)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ud_HB-medlem(sektor)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Ingen Hverv` = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Andre hverv` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Andre afdelingshverv` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Bestyrelsesudvalg = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Sektorbestyrelse = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Gæstelærer = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_2. HB-suppl. (sekt)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Afdelingsbestyrelse = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Afd. daglige ledelse` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_SOSU-uddannelsesråd` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Afd. sektorformand` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Fanebærer = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Sektornæstformand = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Kritisk revisor` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_Fællesbest. SOSU` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),  `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_HB-medlem(sektor)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_FoaHvervTypeNavn_ind_1. HB-suppl. (sekt)` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_Tillidshverv_ind_MED SU/AMO nederste` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_Tillidshverv_ind_MED SU/AMO næst nederst` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Hverv_Tillidshverv_ind_Lokalt MED udvalg supp.` = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you add the output from `dput(head(data_train))`, so we can peak at your data?

Comment: Was only allowed to at most of the data due to 30.000 character limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Your variable names are unclean. For instance, they include spaces.

**Solution**

To use the formula interface, you must first clean up the variable names. An easy alternative is to use the `janitor` package. For instance:

```
library(janitor)

data_train <- clean_names(data_train)

model_reg_tree <- train(
  outcome ~ .,
  data = data_train, 
  method = 'rpart',
  tuneLength = 10,
  trControl = kontroller_cv
)
```

---

**Alternative solution**

You can still use the `x =, y=` interface without cleaning the names, but then you should not provide the data argument. (However, I strongly suggest that you clean the variable names). For instance:

```
model_reg_tree <- train(
  x =  data_train[, names(data_train) != "Outcome"],
  y = data_train$Outcome,
  method = 'rpart',
  tuneLength = 10,
  trControl = kontroller_cv
)
```

Comment: When I used the Alternate solution, it still throws error saying, please provide name of columns.                                                                                                                train(x = trainWithEncodedData[, names(trainWithEncodedData) != "bikeCount"],
y = trainWithEncodedData$bikeCount, method = 'rpart', trControl = trnControlRpart) 
Error: Please use column names for `x`

Comment: Not sure what the problem is in your case. Feel free to ask your own question (with a reproducible example), and I am sure you'll get help! However, I would suggest using the formula interface and having clean variable names.